# Why can't I insert 14 rows at one time into DB

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I use the MVC model, CodeIgniter framework. I try to insert 14 rows into my DB when I try to insert fewer (like 9 or 10) rows it works. I don't understand the logic. The $data array accepts the whole 14 rows but for some reason, the DB doesn't accept it.

This is the Controller:

```
public function saveFinalShifts(){        
        $data = array();

        $newDate= $this->input->post('week');
        $sunday = $this->Shifts_model->getStartDate($newDate);

        $dates = array_fill(0,14,$sunday);

        $days = $this->input->post('day[]');
        $times = $this->input->post('time[]');
        $worker_names = $this->input->post('worker_name[]');

        if(is_array($dates)){
        foreach ($dates as $key => $date){
            $data[] =  array (
                'date' => $date,
                'day' => $days[$key],
                'time' => $times[$key],
                'worker_name' => $worker_names[$key],
                );
            }
        }

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Submitted!');
            $this->Shifts_model->saveFinalShifts($data);
            redirect(base_url("/Shifts/manageShifts"));

    }
```

This is my Model:

```
public function saveFinalShifts($data) {
        $this->db->db_debug = FALSE;
        $error = NULL;
        if (!$this->db->insert_batch('final_shifts', $data)) {
            $error = $this->db->error();
        }
        return $error; 
    }
```

When I try to: `echo '<pre>';print_r($data); die;`

You can see that each of the 14 rows are in the $data array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => sunday
            [time] => morning
            [worker_name] =>victoria
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => monday
            [time] => morning
            [worker_name] => victoria
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => tuesday
            [time] => morning
            [worker_name] => victoria
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => wednesday
            [time] => morning
            [worker_name] => victoria
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => thursday
            [time] => morning
            [worker_name] => victoria
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => friday
            [time] => morning
            [worker_name] => victoria 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => saturday
            [time] => morning
            [worker_name] => victoria 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => sunday
            [time] => evening
            [worker_name] => victoria
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => monday
            [time] => evening
            [worker_name] => victoria
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => tuesday
            [time] => evening
            [worker_name] => victoria 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => wednesday
            [time] => evening
            [worker_name] => victoria
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => thursday
            [time] => evening
            [worker_name] => victoria
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => friday
            [time] => evening
            [worker_name] => victoria
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => saturday
            [time] => evening
            [worker_name] => victoria
        )

)
```

Comment: If there is a problem, wouldn't you want to look at your `$error` variable?  Currently that is ignored.  If you're going to check for errors, you also need to handle them, ie display them or log them.  Separately, your PHP and/or web server logs might also tell you what is going on, have you looked at them?

Answer (score 0):

Try chunking the array.

```
foreach(array_chunk($data, 5) as $chunk){
     $this->db->insert_batch('final_shifts', $chunk);
}
```